# Example 1 of Telegram bot menu access using Google Sheets Apps Script

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script, telegram-bot

0stone0: fixed the problem; thank you, thank you + thank you;

ADW: thank you for illustrating keyboard object, adopted;

Google web app based on JavaScript to send JSON objects to a Telegram bot; implementing Telegram based menu using buttons, in order for the user to press selected button and execution of corresponding action;

user types: menu

list of buttons show up on the Telegram group screen

solution follows:

```
function menu( chat_id ) {
    let url = vUrlTelegram + "/sendMessage";

    var keyboard = {
        'inline_keyboard' : 
        [
            [{'text' : 'admin',      'callback_data' : 'admin'}], // Row 1 
            [{'text' : 'squad',      'callback_data' : 'squad'}], // Row 2

            [{'text' : 'carioca',    'callback_data' : 'carioca'}], // Row 3
            [{'text' : 'brasileiro', 'callback_data' : 'brasileiro'}], // Row 4

            [{'text' : 'sponsors',   'callback_data' : 'sponsors'}], // Row 5       
            [{'text' : 'test',       'callback_data' : 'test'}] // Row 6       
        ]
    };  

    var data = {
        'chat_id': chat_id,
        'text': "main menu",
        'reply_markup': keyboard
    };   

    var options = {
        'method' : 'post',
        'contentType': 'application/json',
        'payload' : JSON.stringify(data)
    };
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);  
    Logger.log(response);
}
```

Comment: I see what you tried, but it's not possible for us to recreate your issue just by looking at this code. If you could log some of these values and tell us what the values are, instead of saying "they aren't working", someone might be able to spot something. :)

Comment: saglamcem; understand your comments, 0stone0 was on top and end up solving the problem; I really appreciate your comments and very grateful for your time; thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just had a busy weekend ;)

Managed to make it work in Google App Script;

```
function myFunction() {
    let token = '123456788:AAdadadadbMTcMvY10SZGsbIJ2rdFXJiXmbFw';
    let url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot" + token + "/sendMessage";

    var options = {
        'method' : 'post',
        'contentType': 'application/json',
        'payload' : JSON.stringify({
            'chat_id': 11111111,
            'text': 'fsdfdsfsdf',
            'reply_markup': {
                inline_keyboard: [
                    [{ text: 'Some button text 1', callback_data: '1' }],
                    [{ text: 'Some button text 2', callback_data: '2' }],
                    [{ text: 'Some button text 3', callback_data: '3' }]
                ]
            }
        })
    };
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);  
    var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
    Logger.log(res);
}
```

Problem was due the nested payload / reply_markup objects.

Comment: 0stone0; 
you are simply the best

WORKS!

thank you very much

I will continue with the implementation

thank you, thank you and thank you

Answer (score 1):

This assumes you are trying to send an inline keyboard to Telegram using Google Apps Script.

I've written this sample script that may help:

```
function sample_inlineKeyboard() {
  var chat_id = '123456789';
  var text = 'Please pick a button:';
  var keyboard = {
    'inline_keyboard' : 
    [
      [{'text' : 'blue',   'callback_data' : 'blue'}, 
       {'text' : 'green',  'callback_data' : 'green'}, 
       {'text' : 'red',    'callback_data' : 'red'}], // Row 1
      [{'text' : 'yellow', 'callback_data' : 'yellow'},
       {'text' : 'brown',  'callback_data' : 'brown'}, 
       {'text' : 'black',  'callback_data' : 'black'}] // Row 2
    ]
  }
  var data = {
    'chat_id': chat_id,
    'text': text,
    'reply_markup': keyboard
  };        
  var options = {
    'method' : 'post',
    'contentType': 'application/json',
    'payload' : JSON.stringify(data)
  };
  var token = "0123456789:AABBCC....."; // Bot token
  var vUrlTelegram = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' + token + '/sendMessage';
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(vUrlTelegram, options);    
  Logger.log(response);
}
```

Comment: ADW; thank for answer; 0stone0 was on top and end up solving the problem your answer is similar to 0stone0; I like your keyboard object, and we will adopt it; great work and thank you for the time; cheers mate